# How Columns_update() Function Works in Trigger To Find Updated Columns Name

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I am confused about trigger function `Columns_Update()`.

I have a basic idea about this function that it returns a `varbinary` and it is use to get updated columns in trigger

Even I have find the code to get updated columns name but have still confusion in bit representation. I would be very thankful if someone explains this function or gives reference

I got the following function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GenColUpdated
(@Col INT, @ColTotal INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN;


DECLARE
@ColByte INT,
@ColTotalByte INT,
@ColBit INT;
-- Calculate Byte Positions
SET @ColTotalByte = 1 + ((@ColTotal-1) /8);
SET @ColByte = 1 + ((@Col-1)/8);
SET @ColBit = @Col - ((@ColByte-1) * 8);
RETURN Power(2, @ColBit + ((@ColTotalByte-@ColByte) * 8)-1);
END;
```

and use that function in trigger like this

```
set @ColUpdatedTemp = dbo.GenColUpdated(@ColCounter, @ColTotal) ;

If COLUMNS_UPDATED() & dbo.GenColUpdated(@ColCounter, @ColTotal) = @ColUpdatedTemp
```

I didn't understand this condition

```
dbo.GenColUpdated(@ColCounter,@ColTotal) =
        @ColUpdatedTemp
```

it doesn't make Any sense to me .First you are assign the value and than Check it

Comment: Reference: [MSDN documentation on `COLUMNS_UPDATED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186329.aspx) - very clearly describes the bit pattern returned by that function

Comment: I had Go through this but i didn't understand very much..:(

Comment: The table's columns are numbered in sequence - and `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` returns a 1 (bit) for each columns that's been updated. Don't know what more to tell you..... the question is: what do you really want to do with this information, assuming you figure out which columns are updated? Maybe there's another approach that figuring out the bit-mask returned by `COLUMNS_UPDATED()` to achieve what you're trying to do ...

Answer (score 0):

You  can check this example of microsoft

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'employeeData')
   DROP TABLE employeeData;
IF EXISTS(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'auditEmployeeData')
   DROP TABLE auditEmployeeData;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.employeeData (
   emp_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   emp_bankAccountNumber char (10) NOT NULL,
   emp_salary int NOT NULL,
   emp_SSN char (11) NOT NULL,
   emp_lname nchar (32) NOT NULL,
   emp_fname nchar (32) NOT NULL,
   emp_manager int NOT NULL
   );
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.auditEmployeeData (
   audit_log_id uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY,
   audit_log_type char (3) NOT NULL,
   audit_emp_id int NOT NULL,
   audit_emp_bankAccountNumber char (10) NULL,
   audit_emp_salary int NULL,
   audit_emp_SSN char (11) NULL,
   audit_user sysname DEFAULT SUSER_SNAME(),
   audit_changed datetime DEFAULT GETDATE()
   );
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.updEmployeeData 
ON dbo.employeeData 
AFTER UPDATE AS
/*Check whether columns 2, 3 or 4 have been updated. If any or all
 columns 2, 3 or 4 have been changed, create an audit record. The 
bitmask is: power(2,(2-1))+power(2,(3-1))+power(2,(4-1)) = 14. To test 
whether all columns 2, 3, and 4 are updated, use = 14 instead of >0
 (below).*/

   IF (COLUMNS_UPDATED() & 14) > 0
/*Use IF (COLUMNS_UPDATED() & 14) = 14 to see whether all columns 2, 3, 
and 4 are updated.*/
      BEGIN
-- Audit OLD record.
      INSERT INTO dbo.auditEmployeeData
         (audit_log_type,
         audit_emp_id,
         audit_emp_bankAccountNumber,
         audit_emp_salary,
         audit_emp_SSN)
         SELECT 'OLD', 
            del.emp_id,
            del.emp_bankAccountNumber,
            del.emp_salary,
            del.emp_SSN
         FROM deleted del;

-- Audit NEW record.
      INSERT INTO dbo.auditEmployeeData
         (audit_log_type,
         audit_emp_id,
         audit_emp_bankAccountNumber,
         audit_emp_salary,
         audit_emp_SSN)
         SELECT 'NEW',
            ins.emp_id,
            ins.emp_bankAccountNumber,
            ins.emp_salary,
            ins.emp_SSN
         FROM inserted ins;
   END;
GO

/*Inserting a new employee does not cause the UPDATE trigger to fire.*/
INSERT INTO employeeData
   VALUES ( 101, 'USA-987-01', 23000, 'R-M53550M', N'Mendel', N'Roland', 32);
GO

/*Updating the employee record for employee number 101 to change the 
salary to 51000 causes the UPDATE trigger to fire and an audit trail to 
be produced.*/

UPDATE dbo.employeeData
   SET emp_salary = 51000
   WHERE emp_id = 101;
GO
SELECT * FROM auditEmployeeData;
GO

/*Updating the employee record for employee number 101 to change both 
the bank account number and social security number (SSN) causes the 
UPDATE trigger to fire and an audit trail to be produced.*/

UPDATE dbo.employeeData
   SET emp_bankAccountNumber = '133146A0', emp_SSN = 'R-M53550M'
   WHERE emp_id = 101;
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.auditEmployeeData;

GO
```